# guardar un .remove() python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo este codigo:

```
while True:
    lista = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]´
   ´jugada = input('dime en que cuadrado quieres que ponga tu cruz').strip()
   ´lista.remove(jugada)
   ´print(lista)
```

si escribes a queda ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'h', 'i']
pero si repites el profeso poniendo b queda ['a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'h', 'i'] en vez de ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'h', 'i']

tambien probé poner en la linea 4 esto:

```
lista = lista.remove(jugada)
```

pero esto da None alguien sabe como hacerlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Explicación

Lo que está pasando es que luego de pedir los datos al usuario y borrar el elemento de la lista, el while se vuelve a ejecutar desde el principio y crea una nueva lista igual a la usada al inicio para luego reemplazar la anterior.

Piensalo así:

```
# Primer dato
lista = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]
jugada = input('dime en que cuadrado quieres que ponga tu cruz').strip()
lista.remove(jugada)
print(lista)

# segundo dato
lista = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]
jugada = input('dime en que cuadrado quieres que ponga tu cruz').strip()
lista.remove(jugada)
print(lista)

...
```

#### Solución

Crea la lista fuera del bucle while.

```
lista = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]´

while True:
    jugada = input('dime en que cuadrado quieres que ponga tu cruz').strip()
    lista.remove(jugada)
    print(lista)
```